# Button transition in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

2 questions... for some context this is the scenario. I have three buttons on my page, as such:

[image]

1) Is what I am proposing even possible with jQuery? I know you can move items, but is it possible to move/fade out simultaneously? And to move a button (Send) into the place of another button (where Download was)? I was reading http://api.jquery.com/animate/ and it seems you can only move by specifying how many pixels to the left (for example), not "move to where this element is".

2) Assuming it can be done, would it look good. I am trying to think of a nice way to transition from those original 3 options to just the send option - in one line. The original order must be Download/Send/Delete. So if anyone can think of a better alternative I am all ears.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it's possible to do this smoothly. I can write up an answer in about an hour if noone else has done so by then. Meanwhile you may find the [Codrops tutorials](http://tympanus.net/codrops/category/tutorials/) an interesting read.

Comment: That would be great, thank you. I'm looking through the Codrops pages for similar transitions articles now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this smoothly. You can do so by either using jQuery's [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or by using CSS classes and [transitions](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/). I have chosen the latter in my example:

In HTML I have grouped the buttons according to the 2 visible states:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="buttons1">
        <button id="download">Download</button>
        <button id="send">Send</button>
        <button id="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <div id="buttons2">
        <input type="text" id="textInput"/>
        <button id="ok">Ok</button>
        <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In CSS I'm using a `.clicked` class to indicate what should be visible or not. I'm also using `position: absolute;` so I can animate my `left` position easily:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#buttons1{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.5s ease;
    transition: left 0.5s ease;
}
.clicked #buttons1{
    left: -77px;
}
#download, #delete{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
.clicked #download, .clicked #delete{
    opacity: 0;
}
#buttons2{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    z-index: -1; 
    /* We use the z-index here to make sure the input field and buttons are 
    clickable and not obstructed by the invisible "delete" button on top of it */
}
#buttons2.appear{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

And in jQuery I simply `toggle` between the classes when a button is clicked:

```
$("#send").click(function(){
    $("#send").attr("disabled", true);
    $(".container").toggleClass("clicked");

    // Activate the second animation with a slight delay so it looks nicer
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#buttons2").toggleClass("appear");
    }, 300);
});

$("#ok, #cancel").click(function(){
    $("#send").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#buttons2").toggleClass("appear");

    // Activate the second animation with a slight delay so it looks nicer
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".container").toggleClass("clicked");
    }, 200);
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cnppgqhc/1/)

Comment: I tweaked it a little bit (used jQuery to fade instead of CSS), but basically this was perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. 
I've made this just now. It's not perfect but it works.

```js
$("#send").click(function() {
  transformation();
});

$("#ok").click(function() {
  //YOUR CODE FOR SAVE OR WHATEVER...
  reverseTransformation();
});
$("#cancel").click(function() {
  reverseTransformation();
});

function transformation() {
  $("#send").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#download").fadeOut(400);
  $("#delete").fadeOut(400);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#textInput").fadeIn();
    $("#ok").fadeIn();
    $("#cancel").fadeIn();
  }, 550);

}

function reverseTransformation() {
  $("#send").attr("disabled", false);
  var input = $("#textInput");
  input.val("");
  input.fadeOut(400);
  $("#ok").fadeOut(400);
  $("#cancel").fadeOut(400);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#download").fadeIn();
    $("#delete").fadeIn();
  }, 550);
}
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
}
button {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button id="download" class="">Download</button>
  <button id="send" class="">Send</button>
  <input type="text" id="textInput" class="hidden" />
  <button id="delete" class="">Delete</button>
  <button id="ok" class="hidden">Ok</button>
  <button id="cancel" class="hidden">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Does it look good?
Thats totally up to you.
If you have any questions don't be afraid to ask.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Between the two answers I got it working perfectly and it looks great. I used a bit of yours as well (I used jQuery to do the fade instead of CSS).